# What is with this change of unpacking behavior from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, difference, iterable-unpacking

Yesterday I came across this odd unpacking difference between Python 2 and Python 3, and did not seem to find any explanation after a quick Google search.

**Python 2.7.8**

```
a = 257
b = 257
a is b # False

a, b = 257, 257
a is b # False
```

**Python 3.4.2**

```
a = 257
b = 257
a is b # False

a, b = 257, 257
a is b # True
```

I know it probably does not affect the correctness of a program, but it does bug me a little. Could anyone give some insights about this difference in unpacking?

Comment: it really doesn't matter, you shouldn't rely on any interning behaviour... use comparison.

Comment: Python interns numbers in the same expression, I'll find the respective code (had it already for an earlier question :))

Comment: This might have to do with your implementation, and how it caches small integers. Have you tried it with a smaller number than 257? Was the choice of 257 random?

Comment: This is an *internal* implementation detail. Do not rely on it.

Comment: @Nasser I guess 257 was explicitly chosen to not trigger the small integer optimisation.

Comment: @Nasser filmor is right, 257 is not random, if you try any number smaller than 257, you will find it always return True.

Comment: @filmor, I think I understand what you mean, can you please explain a little bit about the rationale behind this change of the actual implementation from Python2 to Python3? Remember to post as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: it's just an optimization. implementation detail.

Comment: This phenomenon doesn't really have anything to do with unpacking - it's all about interning of small integers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with integers. Python 3.x will only bother producing one object for any duplicated (immutable) literals in an expression. Try using floats or strings instead. Some literals are further interned so that the same object is used across multiple expressions. Floats are never interned and only small strings are interned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This behaviour is at least in part to do with how the interpreter does constant folding
and how the REPL executes code.

First, remember that CPython first compiles code (to AST and then bytecode). It then evaluates the
bytecode. During compilation, the script looks for objects that are immutable and caches them. It
also deduplicates them. So if it sees

```
a = 257
b = 257
```

it will store a and b against the same object:

```
import dis

def f():
    a = 257
    b = 257

dis.dis(f)
#>>>   4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (257)
#>>>               3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
#>>>
#>>>   5           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (257)
#>>>               9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
#>>>              12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the `LOAD_CONST  1`. The `1` is the index into `co_consts`:

```
f.__code__.co_consts
#>>> (None, 257)
```

So these both load the same `257`. Why doesn't this occur with:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) 
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b
False

$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:44:52) 
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b
False
```

?

Each line in this case is a separate compilation unit and the
deduplication cannot happen across them. It works similarly to

```
compile a = 257
run     a = 257
compile b = 257
run     b = 257
compile a is b
run     a is b
```

As such, these code objects will both have unique constant caches.
This implies that if we remove the line break, the `is` will return `True`:

```
>>> a = 257; b = 257
>>> a is b
True
```

Indeed this is the case for both Python versions. In fact, this is exactly why

```
>>> a, b = 257, 257
>>> a is b
True
```

returns `True` as well; it's not because of any attribute of unpacking; they
just get placed in the same compilation unit.

This returns `False` for versions which don't fold properly; [filmor links to Ideone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443857/what-is-with-this-change-of-unpacking-behavior-from-python2-to-python3/27445745#comment43331278_27444692) which shows this failing on 2.7.3 and 3.2.3. On these versions, the tuples created do not share their items with the other constants:

```
import dis

def f():
    a, b = 257, 257
    print(a is b)

print(f.__code__.co_consts)
#>>> (None, 257, (257, 257))

n = f.__code__.co_consts[1]
n1 = f.__code__.co_consts[2][0]
n2 = f.__code__.co_consts[2][1]

print(id(n), id(n1), id(n2))
#>>> (148384292, 148384304, 148384496)
```

Again, though, this is not about a change in how the objects are unpacked; it is only a change in how the objects are stored in `co_consts`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, Veedrac! I really did not expect a little weirdness that bugs me to expand to such a detailed insight into how the Python interpreter works.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is actually by accident, as I can't reproduce the behaviour with Python 3.2.

There is this issue http://bugs.python.org/issue11244 that introduces a `CONST_STACK` to fix problems with constant tuples with negative numbers not being optimised (look at the patches against `peephole.c`, which contains Python's optimiser runs).

This seems to also have led to the given behaviour. Still looking into this :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting! I just tested the code in a script, both Python 2 and Python 3 returned True for all cases. Guess only the interactive interpreter is a bit lazy. Anyway, I will accept it as a small optimization of Python 3 over Python 2 before I get too paranoid :)

Comment: I just tried `a,b = 257,257` in Pythons 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4.  Every one of them reported `a is b` as True in the interactive interpreter.  Are you sure about your original experiments?

Comment: Hmm, maybe IPython does something fancy here? A difference between the interactive and the script one is, that the former does `LOAD_CONST 257; LOAD_CONST 257` while in the latter it's folded to `LOAD_CONST (257, 257)`.

Comment: Also, I took these two as hints: http://ideone.com/FZrgt4 (3.2), http://ideone.com/jV64I6 (2.7)